# How to save url Image in documents with Unique reference

Tags: ios, caching

I've downloaded multiple images from url’s . The first time I download them, I want them to be stored in cache. I found the following code to generate unique reference.

```
-(NSString*)cachedImageSystemNameforUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
const char* concat_str = [[url absoluteString] UTF8String];
if (!concat_str)
    return @"";

unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5(concat_str, (CC_LONG)strlen(concat_str), result);

NSMutableString* hash = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    [hash appendFormat:@"%02X", result[i]];

NSLog(@"%@",[hash lowercaseString]);


return [hash lowercaseString];

}
```

It works but I didn’t understand technically what's happening  in that code. I'd appreciate further explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It takes a URL (String) and generated a unique hash out of it, using MD5.

Try setting breakpoints and print statements, then following the logic of the code should be straightforward.